# Ruby on Rails - Route to home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This one is a two-parter. Initially I had just one controller:

```
$ rails generate controller home index
```

...and I made that my root.

Recently, though, I wanted to get the database involved. So I made a scaffold called Daily and switched the root to dailies#index instead of home#index.

That worked just fine.  Everything seems to be working fine.

...only problem is that I want to use home#index for something else... but now I have no way to link to it.

This is my routes.rb file:

```
LiquidAdmin::Application.routes.draw do
resources :dailies


devise_for :users

get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'

get "home/bandwall"
get "home/index" :to => "home#index"
# get "dailies/index"
root :to => "dailies#index"
```

and these are my routes:

```
home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                  home#index
```

I've tried.

```
<% link_to "Home", home_path %>
<% link_to "Home", home_index %>
<% link_to "Home", home/index %>
```

Nothing will get me back to that file... even though it was working just fine when it was the root.

Now all of this could've been avoided if "Plan A" had worked...

Plan A was just to make this Daily scaffold and do something like:

```
<% @dailies.each do |daily| %>
```

This worked as a link from the Daily index... but not as a link from home#index. Which is why I switched the root. I was getting annoyed and it was easier.

So my questions: 1. How do I link to the old home#index? 2. How should I have queried the dailies tables from home#index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Daily` model.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :dailies
get "home/index"
```

Running `rake routes`:

```
dailies    GET    /dailies(.:format)          dailies#index
           POST   /dailies(.:format)          dailies#create
 new_daily GET    /dailies/new(.:format)      dailies#new
edit_daily GET    /dailies/:id/edit(.:format) dailies#edit
     daily GET    /dailies/:id(.:format)      dailies#show
           PUT    /dailies/:id(.:format)      dailies#update
           DELETE /dailies/:id(.:format)      dailies#destroy
home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)     home#index
```

**`app/controllers/dailies_controller.rb`**

```
class DailiesController
  def index
    @dailies = Daily.all
  end
end
```

**`app/views/dailies/index.html.erb`**

```
<%= link_to "Home", home_index_path %>

<% @dailies.each do |daily| %>
  <%= link_to 'A daily', daily_path(daily) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh, man... I probably already had that solution a million times. But the REAL problem is... I had to change the link on BOTH pages... otherwise it would give the same error when I arrived at the next page. That's why I thought I wasn't getting anywhere. But at least you made me think of that! Thanks so much! (I also solved the mystery of the not-loading javascript...) My only remaining opponent is Omniauth!

Comment: For the dailies thing I get "undefined method 'each'" Any ideas about that?

Comment: updated my answer. Again, assuming you have a `Daily` model ;)